# Is it possible to override the .InsertOnSubmit(entity) function to add functionality

Tags: linq-to-sql, overriding

Using LINQ To SQL to insert into an error log, but the client now wants to also send emails on every error that is submitted. Is it possible to override the `DataContext.ErrorLog.InsertOnSubmit` function to also send an email when submit is called without having to change too much code? Or would it be faster and easier to do the 10 or so code updates to send the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to my knowledge, but it is possible to override `SubmitChanges`

```
public partial class DataContext
{
  public override void SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode failureMode)
  {
    var errorLogEntities = GetChangeSet().Inserts.OfType<ErrorLog>();
    base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
  }
}
```